# update array in multiddimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array, and I can not update one of these:

```
public function get_list($query){
    if(mysql_query($query,DB::connect())){
       $result = mysql_query($query);
       if (mysql_affected_rows() != 0) {
           while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $list_annunci[] = array(
              "id" => $row["id"],
              "title" => $row["title"]
            );
            if(mysql_query($immagini,DB::connect())){
            $result_img = mysql_query($immagini);
                if (mysql_affected_rows() != 0) {
                   while ($row_img = mysql_fetch_array($result_img)) {
                        $list_annunci[] = array(
                          "img" => $row_img["path_img"]
                        );
                   }
                }
           }
        }
```

how do I insert the record in the array already declared?
tnx stefania

Comment: Please be more specific? What are you trying to update and what is the result.

Comment: I want add a img values in the array declared up.

Comment: the result is a new array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your `id`s as keys for the original array.

```
$list_annunci[$id] = array(
```

Make the database query returns those ids as well.

```
SELECT id, path_img
```

Then you can inject or update the right group.

```
$list_annunci[  $id  ]["img"] = $row_img["path_img"];
                 ^
                 |
         from $row_img["id"]
```